# Duvida com tema no Primefaces

Tags: java-ee

Bom dia, Alguém sabe como consigo trocar o tema do meu projeto para o adminfaces no web.xml se preciso baixar algo ou apenas mudo no código ?

Comment: Você inclui no POM o tema, e depois chama ele no web.xml. Apenas isso.

Comment: Error loading theme, cannot find "theme.css" resource of "primefaces-admin" library

Comment: Mas você incluiu no POM e atualizou o projeto?

Comment: Sim e segue dando esse erro

Comment: Cola por favor o trecho do seu POM e do seu WEB.xml no seu post.